# Problema com cache Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Tenho um service worker funcionando perfeitamente. O problema é que ele está fazendo cache do usuário deslogado. Então toda vez que atualizo a pagina, mesmo logado, ele mostra o header deslogado. Meu service worker:

```
importScripts("{% static 'js/cache-polyfill.js' %}");
  self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open('testv1').then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
          "/",
          "{% static 'assets/css/all.css' %}",
          "{% static 'assets/js/all.js' %}",
        ]);

      })
    );
  });
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução. Precisei mudar o meu EventListener fetch, de acordo com minha necessidade: **uma home que atualiza frequentemente**. ([Referencia](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache))

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    })
  );
});
```